# Using streams to find a minimum of a list of Date objects from a Map<String, List<Date>>

Tags: java, java-stream

What I tried initially

```
Map<String, List<Date>> subscriberCreatedDateSet = data.stream().collect(Collectors
            .groupingBy(SubscriberActivityAggData::getSubscriberAddress
                    , Collectors.mapping(SubscriberActivityAggData::getEventTime, Collectors.toList())));
```

and then

```
Map<String, Date> subscriberCreatedDate =  subscriberCreatedDateSet.entrySet().stream()
                .map(item->Collections.min(item.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.mapping());
```

this is incomplete because I could not find a way to correctly do it.

```
is there a way to do it properly? or should I loops and o it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do that in single pipeline using `toMap` instead of `groupingBy` as:

```
Map<String, Date> subscriberCreatedDate = data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(SubscriberActivityAggData::getSubscriberAddress,
                SubscriberActivityAggData::getEventTime, 
                BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

*Note* - This saves you from the overhead of `Optional` wrapped values in the resultant `Map` as well.

Comment: could this map have  duplicate records

Comment: What is your definition of "duplicate records"? If it means duplicate keys - No. If it means duplicate values - Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single pipeline:

```
Map<String, Optional<Date>> subscriberCreatedDate = 
    data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SubscriberActivityAggData::getSubscriberAddress,
     Collectors.mapping(SubscriberActivityAggData::getEventTime,
                        Collectors.minBy(Date::compareTo))));
```

The only downside is that you get a `Map<String, Optional<Date>>` instead of `Map<String, Date>`, but since none of the groups can be empty, the `Optional` can't be empty either, so you'll just have to add `.get()` each time you access that `Map`.

For example:

```
Date someDate = subscriberCreatedDate.get("someKey").get();
```

Or, you can run a second `Stream` pipeline on the entries of that `Map` to produce a `Map<String,Date>`.

Comment: No this doesn't work man, I'm getting this  error      no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Date conforms to SubscriberActivityAggData inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Date lower bounds: SubscriberActivityAggData

Comment: it's java.util.Date

Comment: @WindulaKularatne try it now. I forgot that I have to do mapping to Date in addition to minBy

Comment: the choice of performing `Date someDate = subscriberCreatedDate.get("someKey").get();` without the presence check would still be poor, alternatively, one can simply get rid of the wrapped `Optional`  values as suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911290/1746118)